Aiogram 3 ValueError: At least one bot instance is required to start polling
import sqlite3
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Command

API_TOKEN = 'ТОКЕН'
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()


conn = sqlite3.connect('bot.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    points INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    invited_by INTEGER
)
''')
conn.commit()



def add_user(user_id, username, invited_by=None):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?', (user_id,))
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (user_id, username, invited_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                       (user_id, username, invited_by))
        conn.commit()



def add_points(user_id, points):
    cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET points = points + ? WHERE user_id = ?', (points, user_id))
    conn.commit()



@dp.message(Command('start'))
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    command = message.get_command()
    args = message.get_args()
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username

    invited_by = None
    if args:
        try:
            invited_by = int(args)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    add_user(user_id, username, invited_by)

    if invited_by:
        add_points(invited_by, 10) 
        await bot.send_message(invited_by, f"Вас пригласил пользователь @{username}. Вы получили 10 очков!")

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("Реферальная ссылка", callback_data="referral_link"))

    await message.answer("Добро пожаловать! Нажмите кнопку ниже, чтобы получить реферальную ссылку:",
                         reply_markup=markup)



@dp.callback_query(lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == "referral_link")
async def process_referral_link(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
    referral_link = f"https://t.me/YOUR_BOT_USERNAME?start={user_id}"
    await bot.send_message(user_id, f"Ваша реферальная ссылка: {referral_link}")



async def main():
    await dp.start_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

Ошибка:
ValueError: At least one bot instance is required to start polling.


В метод start_polling (ссылка) нужно передать своего бота (или ботов), чтобы начать опрос (polling).
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

